# how to get all possible key-value pairs from python dictionary?

Tags: python, list

```
d = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":4}
```

I'm trying to create a nested list from `d` containing all pairs of key-value:

```
[["a",1],["a",2],["a",3],["b",4]]
```

Should I be using list comprehensions here, or is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
d = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":4}
r = [[a, i] for a, b in d.items() for i in (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a list comprehension because it has to map from one item to another. You are intending to create more items than exist in the `dict`:

```py
d = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":4}
result = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for item in v:
            result.append([k,item])
    else:
        result.append([k,v])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def di(my_dictionary):
    for key in my_dictionary:
        if type(my_dictionary[key]) == list:
            for item in my_dictionary[key]:
                yield [key,item]
        else:
            yield [key,my_dictionary[key]]
```

and just use it by

```
d = {"a":[1,2,3], "b":4}
list(di(d))
```